# Stream.forEach after map operation, why is Object's toString not invoked?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

```
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class Sample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         Stream<Person> stream = Stream.of(new Person("Sriram")); 
     stream.map(p -> p.name = "Ram")
                .forEach(System.out::println); 
  }
}

class Person { 
    String name; 
    Person(String name) { 
         this.name = name; 
  } 
    public String toString() { 
             return "Java"; 
    } 
}
```

I expected that the toString method is called at System.out::print in the forEach. So I thought it will always print Java no matter what the name is? But it produces Ram as an output why is it so? much appreciated any reasonable thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `stream.map(p -> p.name = "Ram")`?  This sets the `name` of each `Person` to `Ram` and then returns the name (not the person), thereby giving you a `Stream<String>` (not a `Stream<Person>`) which you then pass to `System.out::println`.  Did you perhaps mean to write `stream.filter(p -> p.name.equals("Ram"))` instead?

Comment: Thanks @LukeWoodward, I'm preparing for an OCP Java 11 exam 1Z0-817. it is one of the tricky question, I came across. I didn't realize this p.name will be return from Stream.map().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the toString is implemented for the instances of `Person` class, you shall invoke `println` over the objects of `Person` type instead of `map`ping them to their `name` and then printing the `String` type.

So something as simple as

```
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

shall give you the desired output `"Java"`.